# How to format Django's timezone.now()

Tags: python, django

I am trying to autofill a django datetimefield using a timezone aware date.
Using Django's `timezone.now()` outputs `Aug. 21, 2019, 5:57 a.m.`. How can I convert this to `2019-08-21 14:30:59` ?

Comment: You probably should take a look to the [**`DATETIME_FORMAT`** settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATETIME_FORMAT).

Comment: Yes that is what I was looking at, I am trying to autofill a form field, which requires the formats listed in the link you provided, but the timezone.now() function outputs none of those formats, so I need to convert before I can use it. Unless I am using the wrong function entirely

Answer (score 26):

If you want to do the transformation on the backend you can use Django's built in utility [`dateformat`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/dateformat.py).

```
from django.utils import timezone, dateformat

formatted_date = dateformat.format(timezone.now(), 'Y-m-d H:i:s')
```

To get the local time, defined by the current time zone setting `TIME_ZONE`, you can use [`localtime`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/utils/timezone.py#L167).

```
from django.utils import timezone, dateformat

formatted_date = dateformat.format(
    timezone.localtime(timezone.now()),
    'Y-m-d H:i:s',
)
```

Answer (score 9):

It is not clear what you are asking. Your examples show different format and different time values too. Although the time value difference doesn't look like a difference between local and UTC time I'll assume that part of the problem was conversion between time zones.

```
from django.utils import timezone
d = timezone.now()
print(d)
print(d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
print(timezone.localtime(d).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

The output is

```
2021-01-13 07:25:17.808062+00:00
2021-01-13 07:25:17
2021-01-13 18:25:17
```

Comment: Best answer. if you wanted to get only date remove the time part. ie: `d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d))`

Answer (score 5):

You can use the code below:

```
from datetime import datetime

date_string = datetime.strftime(timezone.now(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%s')
```

Link - [Ref](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I believe datetime is a timezone naive format, where timezone.now() is timezone aware in Django. Somehow I need to convert the timezone.now() output

Comment: Edited the code for you. The timezone.now docstring - "Return an aware or naive datetime.datetime, depending on settings.USE_TZ."